# How to properly import Google Maps library into angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I didn't find any satisfying solution in other questions for now:

- When I just add the typings to my app, it loads successfully into my IDE (Visual Code) like any other TypeScript definition file, but I get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'`
- When I `declare var google`, my app builds without errors, but since `google`is declared as `any`, my typings files do not work anymore and I lose TypeScript benefits

How can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about when I write "typings" or "TypeScript definition file"